# James 1:12-16; DRB; is Jesus the only innocent Human being who is tempted?

Tags: romans, sin, james

James 1:12-16; DRB;

> 12 Blessed is the man that endureth temptation; for when he hath been proved, he shall receive a crown of life, which God hath promised to them that love him.
> 13 **Let no man, when he is tempted, say that he is tempted by God. For God is not a tempter of evils, and he tempteth no man.**
> 14 **But every man is tempted by his own concupiscence, being drawn away and allured.**
> 15 Then when concupiscence hath conceived, it bringeth forth sin. But sin, when it is completed, begetteth death.
> 16 Do not err, therefore, my dearest brethren.

From the verses, it's clear that temptation, usually be, for being guilty.

Temptation of Jesus:

- Mathew 4:1-11
- Luke 4:1-13

Jesus **Without Sin:**

- Hebrews 4:15
- 2 Corinthians 5:21
- 1 Peter 2:22
- 1 John 3:5

Jesus **Separated from Sinners:**

- Hebrews 7:26

Is **Jesus the only Innocent** Human Being who is tempted?, N.B: Innocent means Sinless or at least Guiltiless.

And by whom, Satan or God?

Or, Satan is an agent of God, as in Job's story?

Comment: I think this question could be modified to make it in scope, such as by adding references to Jesus being tempted or specific relevant passages in Job. As it stands right now, the questions strikes me as somewhat unclear

Comment: @HoldToTheRod the question is so clear, and fits with the requirements of accepted questions!

Comment: I believe I follow what the question is asking--I was just suggesting how it could be modified so it doesn't get closed (it currently has 3 close votes)

Comment: @HoldToTheRod I hope the closure voters revote for opening.

Comment: What is an ‘*innocent human being*’?

Comment: @Dave innocent=sinless, or at least guiltiless.

Comment: So, were Adam and Eve “innocent”?

Comment: @Dave I am not sure whether the doctrine of original sin is Biblical or not. So, I said Innocent, meaning Sinless or at least Guiltiless.

Comment: @Bagpipes Thank you very much. I hope my post adds new idea. +1 for your comment.

Comment: @Bagpipes I clicked by mistake the flag. I am so sorry.

Answer (score 2):

This question is troublesome. Troublesome because it fails to take into account the biblical expressed source of temptation, and replaces it with a philosophical term - “innocent”.

Temptation has got nothing to do with ‘innocence’ - it has everything to do with ‘flesh’. If you have ‘flesh’, you can be tempted. Jesus had ‘flesh’ therefore could be tempted - irrespective of being ‘innocent’.

All ‘sin’ is committed in ‘the flesh’. And it’s the ‘flesh’ that needs to pay the price. Death. Temptation ‘appeals’ to the flesh. Jesus’s ‘flesh’ hungered after 40 days. Offering the worlds kingdoms appealed to the flesh (pride is all about the flesh).

> **JAMES 1:13** *Let no one say when he is tempted, “I am tempted by God”; for God cannot be tempted by evil, nor does He Himself tempt anyone.*

This verse has proved troublesome for some. But is simple. God is spirit (John 4:24). Therefore He can *not* be tempted. Jesus came in the flesh, therefore He could. Jesus lived

Jesus only did what he heard/saw his Father do. That is, Jesus, although ‘in’ the flesh, lived ‘in the spirit’. Satan [the tempter] can *only* ‘appeal’ to ‘flesh’. And uses the flesh’s ‘desire’ [[lust] as a ‘hook’. Exactly what happened with Eve!

Some say ‘Eve’ was innocent - didn’t make any difference to her being able to be ‘tempted’. No, it was her ‘flesh’ that was the factor, and the serpent ‘appealed’ to that.

> **GEN 3:6** *So when the woman saw that the tree was good for food, that it was pleasant to the eyes, and a tree desirable to make one wise, she took of its fruit and ate.*

Comment: the term Innocent is Biblical, read: Hebrews 7:22 DRB, KJV.

Comment: @salah ? Is that text a typo? Hebrews 7:22 doesn’t have nor imply ‘innocent’.  Or am I missing something? Nevertheless, I was *not* saying that ‘innocent’ isn’t possibly ‘seen’ in the Bible, but that it *cant* be used in relation to or with ‘temptation’. And when it is, then it’s examining this philosophically.

Comment: excuse me, Hebrews 7:26 Douay Reims Bible DRB.

Comment: @salah Interesting that the DRB translates ‘*amiantos*’ as ‘innocent’. Not even Strongs makes that association!

Comment: (The DRB is translated from the Latin Vulgate, not from the Greek.) Up-voted +1 for the excellent points about supposed 'innocence' and the _fact_ that flesh can, in and of itself - in its very nature - be tempted.

Comment: @NigelJ about 10 English translations, rather than DRB, have "innocent" as a translation.

Comment: Satan [the tempter] can only ‘appeal’ to ‘flesh’. What is biblical basis for this idea please? All temptation is of the spirit because it pits the will of Jesus against the will of God.

Answer (score 0):

The Lord is sinless, which means that He is free, naturally free, from even a slightest disposition towards sinning. No person can be tempted to committing sin without pre-existing disposition towards this sin in this person. Thus, the Lord cannot be successfully tempted in principle. But of course in their stupidity both Satan (Luke 4:1-13) and humans (Luke 20:22) tempt Him. But it is the same as if a three-years-old kid throws mud to the sun in attempt to sally it, and even this example of a lovely ignorant child does not fathom the transcendent degree of their stupidity even a tiny bit.

As to the question whether He is the only innocent human being to be tempted, the answer is clear "yes", because He is the only innocent human being in ontological sense who ever existed or will ever exist, because only He not only does not but cannot sin ontologically, because He is inhumanated (ἐνανθρωπήθεις) God and God cannot sin ontologically.

Comment: Do you mean that the whole existence is full of corruption. And that the whole existence has only one perfect Human Being?

Comment: @salah I mean that there has been born only ☝️ human being who had not even a potentiality for sinning, who could not sin for this was an ontological impossibility for Him, for all other humans gave created personalities, whereas He and only He, as the incarnated God-Logos has uncreated personality.

Comment: Yo say 'cannot be _successfully_ tempted'. But is an 'unsuccessful' temptation - still a temptation or is it no temptation at all ?

Comment: @NigelJ Temptation that is in reality, i.e. ontologically unfulfillable is indeed still a temptation from the tempter’s stupid perspective; just like if you throw a stone at a dog and it starts biting the stone believing from its dog-ly perspective that biting harms you; so, is harming happening? Yes, but only in a dog-ly perspective, not in reality.

Comment: @Downvoter Dear Sir, any rational-theological objections?